# Logic Appsからオンプレ上のREST APIを実行したい

Tags: azure

以下の内容についてご存じの方、教えていただけませんか。

### 実現したいこと

AzureのLogicAppsから社内NW上のオンプレ上のREST APIを実行したい。

### 現状

Azureと社内NW間はExpressRoute開通済み

### 知りたいこと

ネットワークの観点で、他に行うべきことはあるか。
統合サービス環境 (ISE)を契約する必要があるのか。(月額費用は上げたくないため、極力他の手段があればそれで実現したい)

Answer (score 0):

「統合サービス環境を利用したくない」ということであれば、Virtual Network 上にリバースプロキシを立てるアプローチはいかがでしょうか。

構成のイメージは次の通りです。

Logic Apps <--インターネット--> リバプロ <--Private Peering--> オンプレ REST API